# Vuetify open navigation drawer likemobile app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, navigation-drawer, vuetify.js

If you resize the window to mobile view you can see the side icon to toggle my drawer by clicking on it. The default drawer of vuetify is very nice but I'd like to open it like in a mobile application.

How can I do to open the drawer and follow the mouse or the finger ? If you don't see what I means, the polymer demo does it. https://shop.polymer-project.org/ you can swap from the left to the right and you can control the drawer on mousedown.

Here is my code and a codepen :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>

    <v-toolbar app class="menu-shadow" color="white" height="64">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon class="hidden-md-and-up" @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title class="text-uppercase ">
        <span class="font-weight-light">My </span>
        <span class="primary--text">App</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-toolbar-items v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn flat :to="link.route">{{ link.text }}</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>

      <v-btn flat color="grey">
        <span>Sign Out</span>
        <v-icon right>exit_to_app</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>

      <v-navigation-drawer app v-model="drawer" app disable-resize-watcher class="primary">
      <v-layout column align-center>
        <v-flex class="mt-5">
          <v-avatar size="100">
            <img src="/avatar-1.png" alt="">
          </v-avatar>

        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" router :to="link.route">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon class="white--text">{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="white--text">{{ link.text }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>


    <v-content>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>

      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLvRgj

Comment: Check the vuetify docs for [Touch Support](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/touch-support)

Comment: I'm not sure it could help me. We can only get the slide position, this doesn't following the finger

Comment: Currently no vuetify-way to do it, but there is a feature request: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3262

Comment: @Traxo Thank you a lot, I didn't see this github issue. I hope it will be released soon. This feature will be awesome.